# c programing what is the meaning of this getchar and EOF and what this code do i didn't understand

Tags: c, getchar

```
count = 0;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c != '\t' && c != '\n') continue;
    if (c == '\n') break;
    if (c == '\t') count++;
}
```

what is the code mean and the `getchar` and `EOF` mean I did not understand

Comment: Please add the declaration of `c` to your example.

Comment: SO is not a replacement for reading the first chapter of your beginner-level C book.

Comment: `EOF` stands for End of File. In the case of standard input stream, EOF is reached upon resource closing or exhaustion, which mostly happens when there is nothing more to read.

Answer (score 1):

The [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) standard function reads a character from the standard input stream.

The returned value is of type `int` (which is "wider" than `char`) since it can also return `EOF` for when input reading failed, generally because the stream was closed. The token `EOF` in the code is simply a constant from the header, it can be declared like this:

```
#ifndef EOF
# define EOF (-1)
#endif
```

So it's literally just an alias for the integer literal `-1` (but I don't think you can rely on the numerical value, use the symbolic name!).

The code loops until `EOF` is detected, i.e. it loops over all characters readable on its standard input stream, and counts the number of times `\t` is found.

It can be simplified a lot, the first `if` is pointless (and the `continue`is of course mis-spelled).

Comment: The OP is confused about EOF. He simply doesn't know that it is a defined constant, so it is worthy to add it to the answer.